# Dreamweaver Won't Resolve Cloned Wordpress Dynamics

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, dreamweaver, mamp

**Problem**: Can't get DW to resolve dynamically-related files from my local clone of an existing live WP page.

**Error:** "Dynamically-related files could not be resolved because the site definition is not correct for this server."

**Method**: I followed this to clone my existing WP site to the mac: http://egalo.com/2012/05/15/clone-live-wordpress-to-local-env/

In a nutshell:

• redirected the .com site in my etc/hosts to 'localhost'.

• Installed MAMP and pointed document root RIGHT into the local folder that has the website (ie. localhost = dev_root).

• Created and imported the database.

• Everything worked fine in Chrome-local site was fully navigational.

• Opened DW and set the local Local Site Folder to dev_root.

• Setup a new server with local setting pointing at dev_root folder with a url of "htttttp://localhost".

• Set that server as remote AND test.

• Set Server Model to PHP/SQL

• Open index.php

• Get the error: "Dynamically-related files could not be resolved because the site definition is not correct for this server."

I can only see it live-no design mode is possible.

**Troubleshooting:**

• Set url in the DW server to "http://$livesite.com"

• Moved website to a subdirectory in order to get out of having to redirect myhttp://$livesite URL to my localhost, and when I tried to access htttttttp://localhost/subdirectory to view the homepage I got a 404 with my page's theme in full effect.

I just can't figure it out! Thank, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered and solved by my same post on the adobe forum: http://forums.adobe.com/message/5947056#5947056

Hi

**MY QUOTE** 
I can only see it live-no design mode is possible.

That is correct, there is nothing to see in design view.

Wordpress is made up of a number of different php files, and if you examine the index.php page you will see that it is just a collection of include files.

To give you a run-down of working with wordpress in Dw see -
httttp://www.adobe.com/inspire/2013/10/wordpress-sites-dreamweaver.html
httttp://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/dw_wordpress_pt1.html

PZ